# force chrome to open downloaded pdf in a viewer

Tags: http, jakarta-ee

I have written the code for downloading a pdf file over http request.

```
 public void downloadDocument(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("id") String docId)
            throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        int accountId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("ownerAccountId");
        Map<String, String> docMap = DbInteractor.getUploadedDocsByDocId(
                Integer.valueOf(docId), accountId);
        String docName = docMap.get("name");
        String typeName = docMap.get("type");
        String[] fileName = docName.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");
               typeName= typeName.replace(" ", "");
        if (typeName.equals("CCD/CCR")) {
            typeName = "CCDorCCR";
        }
        String filename = typeName + docId + "." + fileName[1];
        System.out.println(filename);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                Constants.DOCUMENTS_PATH + filename);
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="
                + docName);
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
```

But the file is getting automatically downloaded in chrome .Is there any way to force chrome  to open this document in a viewer(or to ask for an open with dialog in chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing the browser to download by sending "Content-Disposition: attachment".

Comment: its not working even if i remove the header.I have also tried inline.